# Rendering multiple Razor pages to Html

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an application that uses Markdown in Razor Pages (compiled using a custom `TagHelper`) to display static content. There are about 300 pages worth.

I'm trying to render these Razor pages to html so that I can index the content using `Lucene.net`, in order to provide full text search.

I've managed to create some code (see below) that *works*, but prepends previously rendered content whenever subsequent pages are rendered. That is, when I render the first page it works perfectly but, when I render another page the first page's content is also included and, when I render a third page the first two pages content are included.

I have tried creating the dependencies manually within the method, and I have tried creating a new instance of this class for each page, but always with the same result.

What am I missing?

```cs
public class RazorPageRenderer
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor;
    private readonly IRazorPageActivator razorPageActivator;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public RazorPageRenderer(
        IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor,
        IRazorPageActivator razorPageActivator,
        ILogger<RazorPageRenderer> logger)
    {
        this.razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        this.tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
        this.razorPageActivator = razorPageActivator;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderAsync(IRazorPage razorPage) => await RenderAsync<object>(razorPage, null);

    public async Task<string> RenderAsync<T>(IRazorPage razorPage, T model)
    {
        try
        {
            var viewDataDictionary = CreateViewDataDictionary(razorPage.GetType(), model);

            await using var writer = new StringWriter();
            var view = new RazorView(
                razorViewEngine,
                razorPageActivator,
                Array.Empty<IRazorPage>(),
                razorPage,
                HtmlEncoder.Default,
                new DiagnosticListener(nameof(RazorPageRenderer)));

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContextAccessor.ActionContext,
                view,
                viewDataDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext,
                    tempDataProvider),
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            if (razorPage is Page page)
            {
                page.PageContext = new PageContext(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext)
                {
                    ViewData = viewContext.ViewData
                };
            }

            razorPage.ViewContext = viewContext;

            razorPageActivator.Activate(razorPage, viewContext);

            await razorPage.ExecuteAsync();

            return writer.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.LogError(
                "An exception occured while rendering page: {Page}. Exception: {Exception}", 
                razorPage.Path, 
                exception);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static ViewDataDictionary CreateViewDataDictionary(Type pageType, object model)
    {
        var dictionaryType = typeof(ViewDataDictionary<>)
            .MakeGenericType(pageType);
        var ctor = dictionaryType.GetConstructor(new[]
            {typeof(IModelMetadataProvider), typeof(ModelStateDictionary)});
        var viewDataDictionary = (ViewDataDictionary)ctor?.Invoke(
            new object[] {new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()});
        if (model != null && viewDataDictionary != null)
        {
            viewDataDictionary.Model = model;
        }
        return viewDataDictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very interesting. I might be missing it, but I don't see anything in here that loops over that pages. Is that a code snippet you could share as well?

Comment: Just for troubleshooting purposes: calling 'RenderAsync' sincronously fix your problems?